# Linux Node JS listening on port 80 but not on other ports

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, centos7

I am a starting level at linux...

I got node JS to listen to port 80 and everything works well.

But when trying different ports it doesn't work.

```
Firewalld is not enabled...
```

and when trying in the browser I try localhost:8080

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop firewall if already running

```
 sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

Check the status of iptable

If not already installed then install it using

```
yum install iptables-services

sudo systemctl status iptables
```

Enable the service at boot-time:

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

Managing the service

```
systemctl [stop|start|restart] iptables
```

Saving your firewall rules can be done as follows:

```
service iptables save
```

Start and Enable Firewall with this command

```
sudo systemctl start firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
```

Configure firewall and add Ip and range of ports to be enabled (optional)

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="10.0.0.0/8" port port="11224-12224" protocol="tcp" accept'
```

The above command takes the range of IPs and ports. You need to replace the IP and port range in the above command, make sure to change the x.x.x.x/n , here n is the number of ports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my firewall is not even working. what other thing can cause this?

Comment: When using port 80 it works... but otherwise nothing, the firewall is not enabled, what else can it be?

Comment: For the firewall, you must have iptables defined. have you tried checking iptable status using this command => 
sudo systemctl status iptables

Comment: Then this command will enable firewall => 
sudo systemctl start firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld

Comment: I get a "Unit iptables.service could not be found." ... might be because using CentOS 7?

Comment: Make sure you have the iptables-services package installed